# Automatically give user input yes/no in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, input

I want to give input yes/no automatically rather than through keyboard/user input.

```
user_choice = raw_input("Are you sure want to remove all item (y/n):\n")
if user_choice in('y','Y'):
    statement...
else:
    sys.exit(0)`
```

Comment: Why are you using input in the first place if you want to automatically assign an input?

Comment: Actually above function is used in somewhere and user input is necessary but in other hand I am using this function in another one and that time user interaction is not required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could pass in a flag to your function if you want to bypass the user input and do something like

```
def some_function(flag=None):
    user_choice = 'y' if flag else raw_input("Are you sure want to remove all item (y/n):\n")
    if user_choice in('y','Y'):
        statement...
    else:
        sys.exit(0)`
```